# how to download vitejs with low internet connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, vite

recently I newed my windows so vite js got deleted. I tried to reinstall it but due to bad network connection and filterings from iran government I cant download.I tried many vpns but didnt get it downloaded. can anyone help me. I really got stock. i need it

I tried many vpns but I didnt get the vitejs downloaded

Comment: https://snowflake.torproject.org/ ?

Comment: I cant access snowflake.torproject.org it is filtered so. What a government

Comment: _If you can't download Tor Browser through our website, you can get a copy of Tor Browser delivered to you via [GetTor](https://gettor.torproject.org/). GetTor is a service that automatically responds to messages with links to the latest version of Tor Browser, hosted at a variety of locations that are less likely to be censored, such as Dropbox, Google Drive, and GitHub. You can request via email or Telegram bot https://t.me/gettor_bot. You can also download Tor Browser from https://tor.eff.org or from https://tor.calyxinstitute.org/._

Comment: _"How does it work? The idea behind GetTor is very simple: **Step 1**: Send a request to GetTor (gettor@torproject.org) specifying your operating system (and your locale). Ex: "windows es" **Step 2**: GetTor will send you back a reply with links to download Tor Browser from our supported providers. **Step 3**: Download Tor Browser from one of the providers. When done, check the integrity of the downloaded file by verifying its signature. **Step 4**: If required, get some bridges!"_

Comment: it didnt work. uhhhhhh